# intern unit test: loading modules that need browser context

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, intern

I've written simple unit tests for our controller/Router.. but can't get them run by intern.. The Router module needs to load other modules, e.g. pace.js in this instance, and I needed to add it to intern's config file as a dependency in loader/packages... It then loads the Pace module ok, but the intern's runner fails with 'Reference Error: window is not defined'. Pace module needs to run in browser, but intern seems to be running it in Node context... I'm using the following command:

```
node node_modules/intern/client.js config=test/intern
```

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17285989), ie. taken out the Pace module from loader/packages, and added the testcase only if intern is in host-browser context.. but then intern skips my testcase, as it can't enter in the if(has) block... here is the code i added to intern.js:

```
var suites = [];
suites.push('test/unit/all');

if (has('host-browser')) {
    suites.push('test/unit/app/controller/Router');
}

return {
// ...
    suites: suites,
// ...
};
```

Intern seems to be switching its context to Node, how can I keep it in browser?

Answer (score 2):

`client.js` is Intern's node.js client, which runs tests under Node.js. To run tests in a browser, you either need to use [client.html](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Intern#as-a-stand-alone-browser-client) or run tests using [runner.js](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Intern#as-a-test-runner-for-multi-platform-testing) and a WebDriver server such as Selenium.