# Dojo Intern : Unit test fail when loading dependency from a widget class

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, intern

I'm trying to run a **unit test** using Dojo Intern. My project structure is similar to what I have below. The issue I'm getting is when I try to testing the widget in a stand-alone browser client, I get the following errors:

> *TypeError: undefined is not a function deps: "dojo/cldr/nls/gregorian"*
>
> *TypeError: undefined is not a function deps: "dojo/cldr/nls/number"*

and when I test the widget using in a stand-alone Node.js client, I get:

> *ReferenceError: document is not defined
>       at C:/Repos/trunk/src/main/webapp/js/dojo/has.js:102:37
>       at execModule (C:\Users\yolo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:515:54)
>       at C:\Users\yolo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:504:12
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at execModule (C:\Users\yolo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:499:17)
>       at C:\Users\yolo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:504:12
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at execModule (C:\Users\yolo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:499:17)
>       at C:\Users\yolo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:582:7
>       at guardCheckComplete (C:\Users\yolo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:566:4)*

I'm not sure why these errors are generating. Is it because Intern can't load the other dependencies from the widget foo.js? Can someone please help give me pointers on how to resolve this issue?

---

**Project structure:**

```
/myProject   
    js/   
        app/
            widgets/
                foo.js
        dijit/
        dojo/
        dojox/
    tests/
        functional/
        unit/
            widgets/
                foo.js
        all.js
        intern.js
    node_modules/
        intern/
    package.json
```

---

**all.js**

```
define([
    './unit/widgets/foo'
], function() {});
```

---

**intern.js config:**

```
define({
  proxyPort: 9000,
  proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
  environments: [{ browserName: 'chrome' }],
  tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
  useSauceConnect: false,
  useLoader: {
    'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
    'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
 },
 loader: {
    packages: [  
        { name: 'main', location: 'js/app/widgets' },
        { name: 'dijit', location: 'js/dijit'},
        { name: 'dojo', location: 'js/dojo' },
        { name: 'dojox', location: 'js/dojox' }
 ]},
 suites: [ 'tests/all' ],
  excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

---

**js/app/widgets/foo.js**

```
define(["dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/date",
        "dojo/date/locale",
        "dojo/number",
        "dojo/string",
        "dojox/date/timezone"], function (lang, date, locale, number, string) { ... }
```

---

**tests/unit/widgets/foo.js**

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'main/foo'
], function (registerSuite, assert, main) { ... }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my intern test failing with "document is not defined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285719/why-is-my-intern-test-failing-with-document-is-not-defined)

Comment: If I comment out and run a stand-alone browser client,

        "dojo/date/locale",
        "dojo/number", and 
        "dojox/date/timezone", the test runs but I get an error stating, TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Object.main.convertTime which convertTime() is undefined because it requires those dependencies.